# numerical integration with non-numerical parameters

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I want to integrate numerically.
This is my question:

[click to see my question](https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo?album_id=4758949744&photo_id=9680500069)

I used the following code:

```
   a = Integrate[
 1/(x^2*(1 - ((3/
        4)*((1/4)*Exp[24*(1 - x + (1/10))] - (1/(x - (1/10))^6))/
       g) - (b/x)^2)^(1/2)), {x, 1.01/10, 100}]
c = Integrate[Sin[a], {g, 0, 10}]
d = Integrate[c^2, {b, 0, 10}]
```

but I got an error. 
How can I solve this problem?

best regards

Comment: There is confusion here. `NIntegrate` is used for numerical integration not symbolic. I think, you should try `Integrate` instead if you want to keep the parameters `b` and `g` unassigned.

Comment: @MapleSE-Area51Proposal thank you for your comment. I used this operator but mathematica couldn't solve it so I used NIntegrate. So there is no other way to keep the parameters b and g unassigned?

Comment: a couple of comments, 1) do not use decimals for things that are exact fractions. 2) If you really want the `{0,Infinity}` integral mathematica can handle that and you generally get better performance if you don't try to trick it with finite bounds. 3) worry about the convergence issues  before moving on the the generic parameter problem.

Comment: @george2079 Thank you very much for your comment. How can I handle the convergence issues?

Comment: are those very small numbers (10^-19) actually important to the problem?  Do your parameters have a known range?

Comment: the small number is just an example. We can change it, These parameters have not range, actually after this integration, a(b,g) will undergo another integration for "b" and finally another integration will be used for "g".

Comment: @george2079 I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a[g_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[1/(x^2*(1 - ((3/4)*((1/4)*Exp[24*(1 - x + (1/10))] -
             (1/(x - (1/10))^6))/g) - (b/x)^2)^(1/2)), {x, 101/1000, 
   100}, MaxRecursion -> 200]
c[b_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[Sin[a[g, b]], {g, 0, 10}, MaxRecursion -> 200]
```

at this point `c` works. eg `c[9]->1.74757 - 3.6566 I`

now this should work:

```
d = NIntegrate[c[b]^2, {b, 0, 10}, MaxRecursion -> 200]
```

I suspect it will take a very long time. `c` takes ~10 seconds and figure several thousand evals, so several hours to a day.

errors messages of the sort "Numerical integration converging too slowly" I think can reasonably be ignored, but if you see "failed to converge" you should not trust the result.

Comment: Thank you very much for your good answer. I will send the result here.

Comment: The calculation of d worked quite well and took  2370 seconds and d= 116.828-381.946 I.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
intf[g_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[ 1/(x^2*(1 - (.75*(0.25*Exp[24*(1 - x
                                  + 10^(-19))] - (1/(x - 10^(-19))^6))/ g) -
                                 (b/x)^2)^0.5), {x, 10^(-18), 100}]
intf[#, #] & /@ Range[1, 10]
```

**Edit**

Another way,

```
intf[b_, g_] :=  NIntegrate[..., {x, 0, Infinity}, AccuracyGoal -> 50]
intf[1, 2]
Plot3D[Re[intf[b, g]], {b, 0, 1}, {g, 0.1, 1}]
```

You should follow @george2079 comment, then this might give you THE desired output.

Comment: I used your code but I got an error. I want to integrate the function to find         a(b,g) .

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: @HamedPeyrovedin Explain in your question, what exactly you want?

Comment: I added my question 
https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo?album_id=4758949744&photo_id=9680500069